# Help needed to identify this badge, probably from World War Two

Tags: world-war-two

[image]
Material badge worn on uniform

Comment: Welcome to History SE. Perhaps something to do with mountain rescue? (just guessing here). It would help if you could say more (e.g. what kind of uniform). It would also be a good idea if you checked out the help centre. https://history.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Well [Tyrol-Vorarlberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichsgau_Tirol-Vorarlberg) was an administrative division of Nazi Germany. Not sure what the C.F.O.A refers to though.

Comment: Chemins de fer Ottomans d'Anatolie was German owned, but the geography don't match.

Comment: The top of it is the french flag, and I have found T.F.O.A that stands for 
*Troupes Françaises d'Occupation en Allemagne* (French Occupation Troops in Germany) http://www.francegenweb.org/wiki/index.php?title=T.F.O.A._Troupes_fran%C3%A7aises_d%27occupation_en_Allemagne. Given that Tyrol-Voralberg was in Austria, and that the French occupation zone of Austria was Tyrol-Voralberg, it stands to reason that it would be mean *C(orps?) Français(es) d'Occupation en Autriche* (French Occupation C(orps?) in Austria)

Comment: @SJuan76 Seems correct, Maybe convert the comment into an answer? One question tho, Was Tyrol-Vorarlberg an administrative unit of Post WW1 Austria too? Or was it something the Nazis created and ended with them?

Comment: @NSNoob I would have if I had found any explicit reference explaining what CFOA was, but since I could not find any I hope to help someone with better reference materials about it.

Comment: @SteveBird "Well Tyrol-Vorarlberg was an administrative division of Nazi Germany" - its in Austria

Comment: @bigbadmouse There was no independent Austria after the _Anschluss_  in 1938 till 1945.

Answer (score 5):

This is a uniform patch worn by the Allied French Occupational forces in Austria immediately following the end of WW2. The [French zone of occupation in Austria](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Allied_occupation_in_Austria_%281945-1955%29.png) was referred to by French high command as "le Tyrol du nord et le Vorarlberg", and corresponds with modern day Austrian states of [Tyrol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrol_(state)) and [Vorarlberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorarlberg).
C.F.O.A. stands for *Corps françaises d'occupation en Autriche*.

Comment: A tiny bit of extra sources might be interesting. I'm not locating any reference to "Corps françaises d'occupation en Autriche" with quotes on Google, and only one reference to "Corps d'occupation français en Autriche".

Comment: *Autriche* may have been *Allemagne* at least initially